# Loading animation in Blazor prerendered webassembly app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, progress

I wrote a Blazor WASM application and switched to hosted mode to enable serverside prerendering. It works great but what is still left is that of course, Blazor takes some time to load and start inside the browser.

So while the initial page load is now decently fast, there still is that 1 or 2 second timespan it takes for Blazor to load before I can click on something and use the app.

Is there a way to indicate progress during this phase? I don't want users to wonder why they can't click anything.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here: https://github.com/gwruck/Blazor_WASM_Server because they somehow figured out how to know when the blazor files are loaded...

Comment: Blazor in .Net 7 have loading indicator https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-7/